# Why does LLVM 10.0's GEP fail to compute address of a non-primitive field?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

See this tiny piece of code:

```
%ManuallyDrop = type { i32 }

define void @ManuallyDrop.drop(%ManuallyDrop* %0) {
entry:
  %1 = getelementptr inbounds %ManuallyDrop, %ManuallyDrop* %0, i32 0, i32 0
  call void @forget(i32* %1)
  ret void
}

define void @forget(i32* %0) {
entry:
  ret void
}
```

This compiles and works perfectly, as expected.
But when I try replacing `i32` with some non-primitive type it *fails* with a strange message of `error: base element of getelementptr must be sized`

```
%ExampleType = type opaque
%ManuallyDrop = type { %ExampleType }

define void @ManuallyDrop.drop(%ManuallyDrop* %0) {
entry:
  %1 = getelementptr inbounds %ManuallyDrop, %ManuallyDrop* %0, i32 0, i32 0
  call void @forget(%ExampleType* %1)
  ret void
}

define void @forget(%ExampleType* %0) {
entry:
  ret void
}
```

`LLVM` version - `10.0`

Compiled with `llc`

I tried to figure it out myself, but I have no idea why this might fail -- official docs say that GEP does not dereference anything, it just computes the address, so why is it so difficult for it compute address here?

Comment: Can you try making ExampleType a type with elements, and not opaque? Or make it a pointer in ManuallyDrop

Comment: @Jeppe Sure! And... It works. But why? So okay, I see, in LLVM's terminology `sized` means a non-zero sized type, however I still don't get why it can't compute an address of such a type

Comment: I'm assuming that `GEP` computes the byte-offset into the allocated memory for the instance, and uses the struct types to compute that offset. So the types must be known (I'm assuming). :P

Comment: Well yes, makes sense, but if a type has a size of zero, why can't GEP just return the same address that was given to it, instead of failing *at all*.
But nevertheless, this is another topic and the original one has already been answered. Thank you :)

Comment: And BTW, it seems like I've found a reason - in LLVM types `opaque` and {}` are not the same -- `opaque` does *not* mean a type with no defined body, it means a type with a not *declared* body, i.e. that its body is unknown(similar to C's forward type declaration). That is why it panicked. It all makes sense now.
So the correct solution here would be to stop using `opaques` and use `{}` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as @Jeppe pointed out, the problem here is that `ExampleType` is opaque, and `GEP` requires the type to be a non-opaque(not a zero-length one, because if I replace `%ExampleType = type opaque` with `%ExampleType = type {}` it, unexpectedly, works). That's very strange behaviour but whatever.

Comment: I think opaque is a bit like forward declaring a type. So it might have types inside it, but later declared. So empty and opaque is probably not the same.

Comment: It's not weird. GEP finds the address of something within a larger object given a pointer to the start and the type of the object. To do that, it has to know the sizes of each earlier type within that object's type. If any earlier field has an opaque type it can't find the size, or put differently, all earlier types must be sized. And, complicating matters, some types of earlier fields are types if encompassing fields... but the key is that GEP has to know the size of some types in order to add those sizes to the pointer it gets.